# Media server for webrtc for peer to peer connection

Tags: p2p, webrtc

Hello all I am newbie to webrtc just started to run my first application using localhost i got how to access camera and microphone.i had a question is there any media servers to buy if we want to make peer to peer connection or else any free media servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at OpenTok WebRTC: http://labs.opentok.com/try/

It has a huge library of functionality you can easily use, and supports peer to peer flawlessly.

Comment: is it @rickDonohoe is it free media server buddy

Comment: It is free for all peer-to-peer, it only charges for group conversations although it's WebRTC version doesn't support that yet so fire away. Is it the right thing your looking for? It is extremely well documented so should be quick to try out mate. I'm using it now, it's just a bit annoying that the technology is only there in Chrome 21 as I wanted to implement it through a tablet browser :(

Comment: yaa but it is not the one that i am exactly looking for :( i am having very very simple doubt buddy..I just want to know what media server to be used to connect peer-peer using webrtc.I am having synology media server.Is it enough to connect peer-peer @RickDonohoe

Answer (score 7):

For P2P connections using WebRTC, you can use [serverless-webrtc](https://github.com/cjb/serverless-webrtc/). It's purely client-side, just a bit of HTML + JS + CSS.

Another P2P library on top of WebRTC is [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com).

Alternatively, you can use e.g. [EasyRTC](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc) - an open source WebRTC server based on node.js.

Comment: Good answer just to pay your attention GupShup link are not found

Comment: GupShup is dead, I replaced it with another active project.